# Laravel: undefined method timeline

Tags: laravel

I am extending the Tweety application from Laracast.com. I run info a problem that I struggle to find the source of. (Btw I am using VS Code).

The request handler in web.php:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function() {
Route::get('/tweets', 'TweetsController@index')->name('home');
```

The index method in the tweetscontroller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Tweet;


class TweetsController extends Controller
{
    
    public function index()
    {
        return view('tweets.index', [
            'tweets' => auth()
                ->user()
                ->timeline(),
        ]);
    }
```

In my problems window I get the warning:

```
Tweetscontroller.php app\Http\Controllers 
Undefined method 'timeline'. intelephense(1013) [17,19]
```

But the timeline method is defined in the User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, Followable;
    public function timeline()
    {
        $friends = $this->follows()->pluck('id');

        return Tweet::whereIn('user_id', $friends)
            ->orWhere('user_id', $this->id)
            ->withLikes()
            ->orderByDesc('id');

    }
```

If I login to the aplication I get the error message:

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::links() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\tweety\resources\views\__timeline.blade.php)
```

Anyone a good suggestion?

Kind regards,

HUbert

Comment: the `links` error is because you dont have a pagination object ... the other thing, IDE's aren't always right and they can't run your code ... run the code to find errors, there is no way to know what `auth()->user()` is going to return at run time as it uses an interface, could be a User model, could be a generic User, could be a different model etc

Comment: I do not think that is the problem. I am using __timeline.blade.php in 2 different routes, both with pagination. In one route it works flawlessly, in the other one I have the situation I described.

Comment: where that error is, `links` is not being called on a pagination object, it **seems** like it is being called on a single model instance or relationship object even (based on the actual error message) ... PHP and Laravel aren't going to lie about the error :)

Comment: After I added "->paginate(20)" in the index method in the tweetscontroller.php, the "links()"-error disappears and the page seems to work properly again. The warning in VS Code still exists.

Comment: that warning is meaningless ... it can not know the type of object returned from `auth()->user()` therefor it will always not know about those methods because the interface doesn't have these methods, because only the framework internal uses the interface as the api, we do not on the outside of it